# Change color row Datatable selected when click on button Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatable

I need to change the color of a row in my Datatable when I click on the button 'APPLY'

Here is my HTML code for the rows :

```
<tr role="row" class="odd"></tr>
<tr role="row" class="even selected"></tr>
<tr role="row" class="odd"></tr>
<tr role="row" class="even"></tr>
```

In my inspect tab I can change the background color of the row like this :

```
table.dataTable tbody tr.selected {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

How can I code this in Javascript? I tried this code but I obtained an error :

```
$("#btnApply").click(function() {
        var zz = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
        zz.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
     });
```

The error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined

Comment: `zz` is array-like, try `zz[0].style.backgroundColor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you use jQuery in the first line, Y not to continue using it like that:

```js
$("#btnApply").click(function() {
  $(".selected").css('background-color', 'green');
});
```

```css
table tr.selected {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr role="row" class="odd"><td>aa</td></tr>
<tr role="row" class="even selected"><td>aa</td></tr>
<tr role="row" class="odd"><td>aa</td></tr>
<tr role="row" class="even"><td>aa</td></tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="btnApply" value="click">
```